# Jquery show div in post loop?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, loops

I have this very simple script to show a div onclick. This code is however in a post loop, which causes for the script to break down. Obviously since multiple links and divs have the same class and id. How can i make this script work for every single post for a page with multiple posts? Do i need to do a foreach? Also read something about adding a class in jquery. Anyone can help me out?

```
<style>
div.custhide{display:none;}
</style>

<script>
 function setVisibility(id, visibility) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = visibility;
    }
</script>


    <a class="my-post-like" onclick="setVisibility('custhide', 'inline');";>Click here to see</a>
    <div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" class="custhide" id="custhide">
    Content hidden.
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have tagged it with jQuery, use a jQuery event handler which will show the next element of the clicked anchor

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.my-post-like').click(function() {
    $(this).next().show()
  })
})
```

```css
div.custhide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="my-post-like">Click here to see</a>
<div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" class="custhide">
  Content hidden.
</div>
<a class="my-post-like">Click here to see</a>
<div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" class="custhide">
  Content hidden.
</div>
<a class="my-post-like">Click here to see</a>
<div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" class="custhide">
  Content hidden.
</div>
<a class="my-post-like">Click here to see</a>
<div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" class="custhide">
  Content hidden.
</div>
```

---

If you don't want to use jQuery(supported in IE9+)

```js
function setVisibility(el, visibility) {
  el.nextElementSibling.style.display = visibility;
}
```

```css
div.custhide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="my-post-like" onclick="setVisibility(this, 'inline');" ;>Click here to see</a>
<div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" class="custhide">
  Content hidden.
</div>
<br />
<a class="my-post-like" onclick="setVisibility(this, 'inline');" ;>Click here to see</a>
<div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" class="custhide">
  Content hidden.
</div>
<br />
<a class="my-post-like" onclick="setVisibility(this, 'inline');" ;>Click here to see</a>
<div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" class="custhide">
  Content hidden.
</div>
<br />
<a class="my-post-like" onclick="setVisibility(this, 'inline');" ;>Click here to see</a>
<div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" class="custhide">
  Content hidden.
</div>
<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

> since multiple links and divs have the same class and id

Multiple elements with the same `id` is invalid markup, so at that point any JavaScript behavior on that markup becomes undefined.  So the first concern is to correct that.

Give your elements unique `id` values.  I'm not 100% familiar with Wordpress, but does PHP code work in this loop?  In plain PHP, it might look something like this:

```
<a class="my-post-like" onclick="setVisibility('custhide<?php echo $i ?>', 'inline');";>Click here to see</a>
<div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" class="custhide" id="custhide<?php echo $i ?>">
Content hidden.
</div>
```

Note the appended `$i` value to each `id`.  This is assuming that the loop in server-side code has some incrementing `$i` value.  If it has something else, use that something else.  (Maybe an identifier for the objects/records over which the code is looping?)

Either way, the idea is to append some value which is different in each iteration of the loop, thus making the client-side `id` values different.

Once that's corrected and the markup is valid again, I suspect the client-side code you currently have will still work without modification.